# Gromacs not available in repository in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, package-management

I had ubuntu 11.10 and I installed Gromacs on it from Ubuntu software centre, but I installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently and I can't find the Gromacs simulation software in repository, any comments?

Answer (score 0):

there is a ubuntuUpdates packages in the following link which will solve your problem
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/universe/base/gromacs